# How to create PDFs using zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have some data in a text area and there is a link 'create PDF'. When a user click 'create PDF' link, the data should be printed on an PDF and download window of browser should appear to download that PDF. Any Idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... Zend and PDF.

Maybe [**Zend_PDF**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) is the thing for you? :)

> The Zend_Pdf component is a PDF (Portable Document Format) manipulation engine. It can load, create, modify and save documents. Thus it can help any PHP application dynamically create PDF documents by modifying existing documents or generating new ones from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Zend PDF class](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2525) (tutorial) and POST data.